# If I take a 2-week paternity leave in the UK, do I get a 2-week extension to my work contract?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-extension

If I take a 2-week paternity leave in the UK, do I get a 2-week extension to my work contract, in which I would receive my normal salary? In Norway, I did get an extension, but I am not sure if the same applies in the UK.

I am an employee, not a contractor. I work at a university on a time-limited project funded by a grant.

*Note: I asked the same question in Expatriates.SE, but was advised to ask here instead.*

Comment: If you are an employee why would you need an extension?

Comment: @Ramhound, do you mind explaining your question more?

Comment: Trying to understand how you can be an employee of the company but still have a time-limited contract.  A employee of a company does not normally have a contact, those are normally reserved, for contractors hence the name....

Comment: @Ramhound, I see. I work in the university on a time-limited project funded by a grant.

Comment: @adipro - If the project is time limited its unlikely they will be able to extend it because of your paternity leave.

Comment: @Ramhound, why is that so? I worked under similar contract in Norway, and I did get an extension. During my paternity leave, my salary was paid by the government. It is the same in the UK, as far as I know.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, I asked my HR, but they do not know. I guess I'll ask my manager.

Comment: The phrasing of your contract may be important here.  If your contract is "from X to Y" the result may be different than if it is "for 1 year beginning X".

Comment: @adipro why would your manger know when HR doesn't?

Comment: @Ramhound To give you an idea, in some countries PhD candidates are employees with a three or four-year contracts intended to cover the time needed to prepare a thesis. If you go on parental leave for several months (one year is not unusual in Europe), you obviously need more time to complete your PhD. Since the money for the parental leave typically comes from an insurance-like system or general university budget, getting an extension is usually possible and does not cost your manager/department anything (someone else pays for it).

Comment: Two-weeks is not that long and the OP is probably a post-doctoral researcher but that's where he is coming from.

Comment: @Pepone HR advised me to ask my manager, but my manager wasn't sure either.

Answer (score 2):

My reading of this, as a UK manager is that you are on a fixed term contract.  This is different to usual contracting in that the person is more like a permanent staff member regarding benefits/tax etc during their stint.  It is quite common for things like maternity leave, long term illness or secondment.

You should speak to HR for clarification, but in my experience you would get the same leave as a permanent staff member.  So this means you won't get it added on (a contractor would be taking unpaid leave) but will likely be paid the 2 weeks leave like a perm.

Comment: As I have indicated above, I have spoken to my HR, but they did not know. As an update, I have also spoken to my manager, but my manager also does not know.

Comment: Well if HR don't know they need to find out for you, that's part of their job.  Otherwise tell them I said yes you should ;)

Comment: You mean, I should get an extension?

Comment: Sorry that was an attempt at humour.  Talk to payroll, they will know.

Comment: @adipro tell them i said yes you should too. Don't tell them i was being humourous though, tell them i was *deadly serious*.